# Add incremented property to IEnumerable by group using LINQ

Tags: linq

To simplify the scenario, let's say we have a list of People with FirstName and LastName properties.

Our data looks like this:

```
Bob    Smith
Jane   Smith
Todd   Grover
Larry  Lewis
Jill   Lewis
Frank  Lewis
```

The first step would be to add an Integer property that gets incremented for each item:

```
Bob    Smith  1
Jane   Smith  2
Todd   Grover 3
Larry  Lewis  4
Jill   Lewis  5
Frank  Lewis  6
```

Ideally, I'd like to reset the counter for every new group to achieve this:

```
Bob    Smith  1
Jane   Smith  2
Todd   Grover 1
Larry  Lewis  1
Jill   Lewis  2
Frank  Lewis  3
```

Maybe LINQ isn't appropriate.  It just seems like LINQ should be able to do this elegantly.

Comment: this is the first time ever I know something to do in plain SQL but not in C# (read as "not as quickly using Linq")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want a counter that increments with each item:

```
var query = people
    .Select((x, i) => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName, Index = i + 1 });
```

Or if you want to reset the counter for each group, grouped by `LastName`:

```
var query = people
    .GroupBy(x => x.LastName)
    .Select
    (
        x => x.Select((y, i) => new { y.FirstName, y.LastName, Index = i + 1 })
    )
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

And to quickly display the query results:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.FirstName + "\t" + item.LastName + "\t" + item.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second overload of the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method, which incorporates an index parameter passed to the lambda expression, for example:

```
var people = new [] {
  new { FirstName = "Bob",   LastName = "Smith"},
  new { FirstName = "Jane",  LastName = "Smith"},
  new { FirstName = "Todd",  LastName = "Grover"},
  new { FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Lewis"},
  new { FirstName = "Jill",  LastName = "Lewis"},
  new { FirstName = "Frank", LastName = "Lewis"},
}.ToList();

people.Select((p, index) => new {
                                  FirstName = p.FirstName,
                                  LastName = p.LastName,
                                  Index = index
                                }
             );
```

Result:

[image: select-index]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an integer property already on the record type, and the collection is already sorted, then you can abuse Aggregate (i.e. left-fold), something like this

```
collection.Aggregate( (old, next) => { if (namesDiffer(old, next)) next.Index = 1 else next.Index = old.Index +1; return next;}, aRecordWithEmptyName);
```

EDIT -- fixed return value; fingers had been on autopilot.