# Entity Framework incremented index property for groups

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'd like to have an int property that is incremented for each item in group independently (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280351/add-incremented-property-to-ienumerable-by-group-using-linq), because quotes need to be accessible like `/person/quote/1..2..3` not `/person/quote/1..5..10`:

```
Quote  Person  Index
Lorem   Smith  1
Ipsum   Smith  2
Loremi  Lewis  1
Ipsumi  Lewis  2
```

Using code in that question with EF:

```
var query = _data.Quotes
    .GroupBy(x => x.Person.Name)
    .Select
    (
        x => x.Select((y, i) => new { y.Text, y.Person.Name, Index = i + 1 })
    )
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

But EF cannot parse it and returns `NotSupportedException` exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`2[System.String,System.Int32]] Select[Quote,<>f__AnonymousType9`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[App.Models.Quote], System.Func`3[App.Models.Quote,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType9`2[System.String,System.Int32]]) and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Comment: Add `.ToLower()` to every string in the query and run again

Comment: Simply retrieve the grouped data by inserting a .ToList in the query in a location that Linq to Entities still can understand. After that you are in LINQ to Objects and can apply the indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **Dabblernl's** comment this code is working:

```
var query = _data.Quotes
    .GroupBy(x => x.Person.Name)
    .ToList()
    .Select
    (
        x => x.Select((y, i) => new { y.Person.Name, y.Text, Index = i + 1 })
    )
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Does it affect performance? With ToList() I retrieve all columns etc. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Measure and thou shalt know! :-) You can try to project (Select) the values into a custom class that only contains the fields you need before calling ToList.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
 var query = _data.Quotes
  .GroupBy(x => x.Person.Name.ToLower())
  .Select
  (
    x => x.Select((y, i) => new { y.Text.ToLower(), y.Person.Name.ToLower(), Index = i + 1 })
  )
  .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. Even when I use Name = y.Person.Name.ToLower() still the same NotSupportedException described in question.

Comment: Can you first check if string is null or empty ?